# Polynomial in Compact Polytope: PolynomialReduce with positive "poly" terms and zero remainder?

Tags: polynomials, algebra

***Context:*** I am trying to code a function in Mathematica by which I can check whether a polynomial is non-negative in some compact polytope such as specified by interval values for each variable. This is very much relevant to this publication [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102689794) on Handelman's theorem. Relevant problems [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868615/handelmans-theorem-on-nonnegative-polynomial-in-compact-polytope) with focus on Mathematics and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725193/polynomial-reduction-polynomial-in-terms-of-other-polynomials) with focus on programming.

Consider a polynomial. Can we make Mathematica to return terms in PolynomialReduce command such that each term is positive and remainder zero otherwise alert that no solution?

**How to find the positive linear combination of products of members of $\{\beta_i\}$ for a polynomial $f$ where each $\beta_i$ corresponds to a constraint on variables of $f$?**

*Example*

> I need to find out a way to specify to Mathematica that each term must be positive in the return.
>
> The third term $-x_1$ is negative because $0.2\leq x_1\leq 0.5$. We transform the inequalities to linear form and then try to apply the Handelman's theorem, originally also inequality $0\leq x_2\leq 1$ and $x_3=1$
>
> ```
> PolynomialReduce[
>  x3 - x1*x2 - 2, {x1 - 0.2, -x1 + 0.5, x2, -x2 + 1, 
>   x3 - 1, -x3 + 1}, {x1, x2, x3}]
> PolynomialReduce[
>  x3 - x1*x2, {x1 - 0.2, -x1 + 0.5, x2, -x2 + 1, x3 - 1, -x3 + 1}, {x1,
>    x2, x3}]
> PolynomialReduce[
>  x3 - x1*x2 - 1, {x1 - 0.2, -x1 + 0.5, x2, -x2 + 1, 
>   x3 - 1, -x3 + 1}, {x1, x2, x3}]
> ```
>
> and [its picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8FE6.png), where the result of PolynomialReduce cannot be used because of the negative terms. The Handelman requires to find positive linear combination of products of members of $\{\beta_i\}$ where $\beta_i$ terms are the linearised form of each inequality.

Comment: (1) Actual code is much better than an image of code. (2) You should recheck documentation for `PolynomialReduce`. Giving a pair of polynomials such as `x-1/5,x-1/2` is tantamount to stating that 1 is in the ideal. (3) Almost certainly it is the wrong tool for this situation. Some form of quantifier elimination might be needed.

Comment: Re, "compact polytope" - polytopes are compact by definition.

Comment: Polytopes can be unbounded.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau does the compact polytope infer that polytopes are not unbounded? Why does Handelman's theorem stress the word `compact` instead of `unbounded`? The case I am interested is polytopes restricted by inequalities of the form $x_i^{lowerBound}\leq x_i\leq x_i^{upperBound}$ so compact bounded polytopes, good choice of vocabulary?

Comment: Compact means bounded, yes, Also means weak inequalities, that is to say, it includes its boundary.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau can you clarify `"Giving a pair of polynomials such as x-1/5,x-1/2 is tantamount to stating that 1 is in the ideal."`? The ideal must be non-empty $0\in I$ but what do you mean by tantamount that $1\in I$?

Comment: Think of `PolynomialReduce` as working on equations (it most certainly does not deal with inequalities). If you have equations `{x==1/5,x==1/2}` then your ideal contains 1: `In[435]:= GroebnerBasis[{x == 1/5, x == 1/2}, x]

Out[435]= {1}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I agree that PolynomialReduce is not what needed here: I need to find a command `PolReduce2[poly,{poly1,...,polyN},{x1,...,xH}]` that returns `a1*poly1 + a2*poly2 + ... a_N polyN + b` where `b=0`. Any such command in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

One way to check whether a polynomial can go negative on a polytope is to find the minimum. In this case it can be as small as -3/2.

```
Minimize[{x3 - x1*x2 - 2, {1/5 <= x1 <= 1/2, 0 <= x2 <= 1, 
   x3 == 1}}, {x1, x2, x3}]

(* Out[434]= {-(3/2), {x1 -> 1/2, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: How can you solve the non-negativity with some algebraic geometric method without minimizing directly? See [Example 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868615/handelmans-theorem-on-nonnegative-polynomial-in-compact-polytope) where each inequality corresponds to a product term $\beta_i$ to form the set $\{\beta_i\}$. The problem is to find $f=a_1\beta_1+\ldots+a_n\beta_n$ where remainder is zero to use the Handelman's theorem without minimizing the function directly.

Comment: My point is simply that it will be very difficult to write it as a nonnegative sum on that polytope, since it happens not to be nonnegative thereon.

Comment: Prof. Handelman sees in terms of product of simplices (apparently simplicial complexes) & aff equivalance [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/245080/36875): `"if the polytope is not so equivalent, then the positivity condition is much more difficult"` -- he refers to his more recent publication but I cannot understand it: what is *"praise"* in title *"In praise of order units"*? They show that ordered rings associated to compact convex polyhedra with interior satisfy a positivity property known as order unit cancellation. Can you understand how this could be used for algebraic geometric solution?

Comment: This area is not familiar to me.

Comment: On `*"My point is simply that it will be very difficult to write it as a nonnegative sum on that polytope, since it happens not to be nonnegative thereon"*` -- yes but we can use Handelman's theorem two times first for positive polynomials and then for negative polynomials. Polynomials that are not negative and not positive must be zero polynomials and hence non-negative, right?

Comment: (1) I don't follow that at all. A polynomial can be positive on some part of a polytope and negative on other parts, hence is neither positive nor negative everywhere. (2) If the idea is to split the polynomial into a difference of two positive parts, it won't work. Reason: there must be points where it is zero, and existence of such points means Handelman's result does not apply (hypotheses are not met).

Comment: Everywhere in compact polytope: polynomial $f(p)$ on a compact polytope $K$ such as $p\in K$ for probability vector can be everywhere positive, negative, zero, non-negative or non-positive. So Handelman's theorem can only be used to find negative polynomials and positive polynomials on some given polytope. Because of zeroes w non-negative or non-positive polynomials on $K$, Handelman's theorem cannot be used on them. You suggest that some version of NichtNegativstellensatz to be more appropriate for non-negativity than the Handelman?